Fast Report - Saltar a la siguiente columna de la página
estoy haciendo un reporte con varias columnas por página pero tiene un group header y me gustaría poder cambiar de columna cuando el group header cambia y no lo consigo, en la imagen lo que está remarcado en amarillo es lo que debería saltar a la siguiente columna.
Gracias.


Hola, ya lo he solventado, en el beforeprint de la banda que se quiera imprimir en otra columna: Engine.NewColumn

En StackOverflow se alienta a que escribas tu propia respuesta si encontraste la solución a tu problema, así que, adelante!  Recuerda incluir una explicación que resulte útil para futuros navegantes, quizás un ejemplo o algo de código. Lee [answer] para tomar inspiración.
